# Lua socket HTTP getting connection refused

Tags: sockets, http, lua, github-api

I'm trying to create a function that creates an issue to a Github repository using Lua `socket.http`, but I'm getting connection refused everytime. The documentation for socket is a bit unclear and I couldn't find more helpful information on why is the request getting refused every time. I tried the following:

```
local config = {
    token = "oauth token from github"
}

local http, ltn12 = require("socket.http"), require("ltn12")
local payload = '{"title": "Test", "body": "Test body", "labels": ["bug"]}'
local response, status, headers, line = http.request("https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repository>/issues?access_token=" .. config.token, payload)
```

So I checked again how to do and there is a second form to do a request. I'm trying the following:

```
local response = {}
local _, status, headers, line = http.request{
    url = "https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repository>/issues",
    sink = ltn12.sink.table(response),
    method = "POST",
    headers = {
        ["Authorization"] = "token " .. config.token,
        ["Content-Length"] = payload:len()
    },
    source = ltn12.source.string(payload)
}
```

According to socket documentation, this should make POST request to the URL sending the payload as body. If I `print(status)` it prints `connection refused`.

I'm ignoring the first return value as it always is 1.

I tried manually issuing the request using curl:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token <oauth token from github>" https://api.github.com/repos/<username>/<repository>/issues -XPOST -d '{"title": "Test", "body": "{"title": "Test", "body": "Test body", "labels": ["bug"]}'
```

And it posted the issue properly. I still can't figure it out what is happening that the connection is getting refused.

Comment: Do you have something (like luasec) that can handle the ssl part of `https`? Like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8286677/258523)?

Comment: No, I wasn't. I downloaded and compiled luasec and using it says `/usr/lib/lua/5.1/ssl.so: undefined symbol: luaL_setfuncs` and it doesn't work. I'm using Lua 5.1 through LuaJIT 2.0.4.

Comment: `luaL_setfuncs` is a lua 5.2+ function. You compiled luasec against lua 5.2 or 5.3 and then installed it in a lua 5.1 directory it sounds like.

Comment: No, not really. Lua version is set to 5.1 on luasec makefile and I only have 5.1 on my computer.

Comment: Can you show the compilation command that make ran for luasec? Can you run `nm /usr/lib/lua/5.1/ssl.so`?