# How to send web requests using LuaSocket

Tags: lua, webrequest, luasocket

How exactly do you use LuaSocket to send web requests?

Comment: [http request](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/http.html) , [https request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286677/https-request-in-lua)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https request in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286677/https-request-in-lua)