# Getting A Link Information In Lua

Tags: http, web, printing, lua, hyperlink

How can I get link text using Lua?

My link is:

'''https://shahedtabriz.000webhostapp.com/Filex.txt'''

I need to get "Please Print This Text" using Lua.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https request in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8286677/https-request-in-lua)

Comment: What host application your Lua script is running in?

Comment: This question could be improved by using an example.com as the usable link, as the link shown will likely expire relatively soon and remove question context for future users.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
result = HTTP.SubmitSecure("https://shahedtabriz.000webhostapp.com/Filex.txt",
   {request="check_user"}, SUBMITWEB_GET, 20, 443, nil, nil);
result = Dialog.Message("Notice", result, MB_OK, MB_ICONINFORMATION, MB_DEFBUTTON1);
```